# Can you stack legendary proportions and giants form 2?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, creature-size, stacking

I just did a lot of research for a [different but related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/83889/23058) and while doing so discovered something which I would like confirmed:

We are all familiar with how [enlarge person](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person) works, and how it cant be stacked with other size increasing magics.

During my research I came across the transmutation spell [Legendary Proportions](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/legendary-proportions) which does not have that line.

I also came across the transmutations polymorph spells [Giant Form 2](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/giant-form-i) and [Monstrous Physique 3](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/monstrous-physique-i), both which allow you to become huge while staying humanoid.

So if you were to have the polymorph spell cast on you first, and then the transmutation spell, would this not make you gargantuan?

Bear in mind that none of the listed spells contain the type of ruling which states different magical size increases do not stack, those are specific to spells, I cant find an outside spell description ruling stating this. Since legendary proportions is not a polymorph, it doesnt interact with the ruling for how you can only be under the effect of one polymorph spell.

So, would you become a gargantuan humanoid or is there a rule somewhere that I have not found?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**No.**

From the [polymorph subschool](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Transmutation-Polymorph):

> You can only be affected by one polymorph spell at a time. If a new polymorph spell is cast on you (or you activate a polymorph effect, such as wild shape), you can decide whether or not to allow it to affect you, taking the place of the old spell. In addition, **other spells that change your size have no effect on you while you are under the effects of a polymorph spell.**

While the above rule is enough for your case, there is also a [Paizo FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9t5u) which says that size changes never stack, even for spells that lack a non-stacking clause:

> As per the rules on size changes, size changes do not stack, so if you have multiple size changing effects (for instance an effect that increases your size by one step and another that increases your size by two steps), only the largest applies.

However, I can't actually find the "rules on size changes" that the FAQ refers to. So afaict, like many FAQ entries, this is an errata and not just a clarification of previously existing rules.